# Working with subset of Angular JS model

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Here is my model:

```
   var nav = [{
        label: 'Pages',
        value: '#',
        toggle: 'dropdown', // set this to '' when the menu has no children
        children: [{
            label: 'Home',
            value: 'home'
       }, {
            label: 'Left Nav',
            value: 'leftnav'
        }, {
            label: 'Two-Panel Selector',
            value: 'two_panel_selector'
        }]
    }, {
        label: 'Components',
        value: '#',
        toggle: 'dropdown',
        children: [{
            label: 'Lists & Tables',
            value: 'lists_tables'
        }]
    }, {
        label: 'Elements',
        value: '#',
        toggle: 'dropdown',
        children: [{
            label: 'Text',
            value: 'elements?section=Text'
        }, {
            label: 'Buttons',
            value: 'elements?section=Buttons'
        }, {
            label: 'Alerts',
            value: 'elements?section=Alerts'
        }, {
            label: 'Inputs',
            value: 'elements?section=Inputs'
        }, {
            label: 'Icons',
            value: 'elements?section=Icons'
        }, {
            label: 'Sample Grid',
            value: 'elements?section=Grid'
        }, ]

    }];

    return {
        getNavData: function() {
            return nav;
        }
    };
```

I would like to work with the "Elements" children in a list.  This works fine, but I am wondering if there's a way without using the array index as I have done:

```
div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="l in navData[2].children" ng-class="{'active': l.label == submenu}" ng-click="select(l.label)">{{l.label}}</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the element in your array like this:

```
<a ng-repeat="l in elementsChildren()"></a>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.elementsChildren() = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) {
    if (nav[i].label === 'Elements')
      return nav[i].children;
    return [];
}
```

This means that if 'Elements' is moved within the array, your view won't break. However, this is more expensive. You will now be iterating over the array to find 'elements' (`O(n)`), as opposed to indexing directly into your array (`O(1)`).